# OracleException:inconsistent datatypes: expected NCHAR got NCLOB

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, linq, group-by

I have following query, trying to group Expenses by year and month. I am using EF with oracle DB and getting following exception:

> OracleException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NCHAR got
>   NCLOB

```
var result = context.Expenses
                    .GroupBy(g => new { g.Date.Month, g.Date.Year })
                    .Select(g => new ExpenseBO { MonthAndYear = g.Key.Month + "/" +g.Key.Year , Price = g.Sum(x => x.Price) }).ToList();
```

Anyone knows why am I getting this exception or what am I doing wrong? THanks

Comment: the code is expecting a single character, it's getting an entire CLOB

Comment: Your data layer has a different data type then your database for one of your properties. Please check, if any of your properties has either an attribute [StringLength(InsertYourLengthAsInt)] or you spedified string length via StringPropertyConfiguration.
Code First generated columns from string properies are added as NCLOB, not NCHAR/NVARCHAR.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith NCHAR isn't necessarily a _single_ character

Comment: @nilsK I checked my properties and they do have attribute StringLength. In my Database are these string properties added as VARCHAR

Comment: @nilsK, yes, i meant to say one or more characters. but the error message is pretty self explanatory

Answer (score 1):

go to your model and set the lenth for your field:

```
public class MyTable
    {
        [Key]
        public virtual int id { get; set; }
        // A column which contains any text
        [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 0)]
        public virtual string string my_text_column { get; set; }
    }
}
```

migrate your changes to the DB.